# How to trigger AWS Lambda on CloudWatch schedule + SQS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I know that AWS Lambda can be invoked by CloudWatch scheduler as well as by SQS event, but can they be used together in logical "**and**" combination?

Basically, what I need is to run my lambda every minute (for example) **only when messages available in SQS**. Is it even possible with AWS config only?

I need this to be able to utilize some third-party API with hard API limit, that's why I cannot  just use SQS event (easy to break the limit) and I don't like the idea to use scheduler only, because it will be useless when queue is empty.

Comment: Thought-provoking question -- thanks for that. Do you recall what kind of solution  you ended up going for?

Answer (score 1):

While this is a cool idea, this is unfortunately not possible - event sources in Lambda are always separate from each other. I understand your impulse to save CPU-cycles and API-calls (and money), but I think the only solution that works is your proposed put-it-on-a-timer-and-poll-sqs one.

I was searching the documentation for references on this, but couldn't find any.